Input-Output Model. Trying to optimize gross output given a labor constraint.
I'm trying to create a simple IO model for a planned economy with the goal of optimizing gross output given some labor constraint.
I started off like that:
Matrix of technical coefficients - $A$
Matrix of gross outputs - $g$
Matrix of final consumption - $f$
The gross output of some product i would be  expressed in the following equation: $$ G_i = a_{ii}G_i + F_i + \sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{ij}G_j$$
In which $a_{ij}$ is the technical coefficient representing the amount of product i required for the production of one unit of product j, $G$ is gross output and $F$ is final consumption.
After  that I decided to express the equations for all gross outputs as a matrix since its easier.  Using the matrices defined above we get:
$$Ag + f = g$$
Which should look like this:
$$\begin{bmatrix}a_{ii} & \cdots & a_{ij}\\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\\ a_{ji} & \cdots & a_{jj}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} G_i \\\ \vdots \\\ G_j \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} F_i \\\ \vdots \\\ F_j \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} G_i \\\ \vdots \\\ G_j \end{bmatrix} $$
By solving for $g$ we get the following:
$$ (I-A)^{-1}f = g $$
In which $I$ is an $n$x$n$ identity matrix with $n$ being the number of industries.
I can obviously get any gross output but that doesn't mean I'll be actually able to produce it all. That depends on the current labor supply and the labor required for the production of the gross output that the equation gave me. The required labor supply we can get by defining a new matrix called $L_c$ which is a 1x$n$ matrix with labor coefficients. An example of a labor coefficient would be $l_{i}$ which states the required labor per unit of product i for its production. After defining it, we multiply it by the gross outputs matrix $g$. Thus:
$$ L = \begin{bmatrix} l_i & \cdots & l_j \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} G_i \\\ \vdots \\\ G_j \end{bmatrix} $$
This will result in a 1x1 matrix which can be interpreted as a vector with only one component. Thus its length must be the absolute value of that component. So:
$$ L_r = ||L|| $$
We also have our current labor supply which I'll denote as $L_s$. The objective is: $$L_r = L_s$$
My question is: How can I use all of this to optimize for the maximum possible gross output without violating the labor supply constraint. I think the answer should tell me that in terms of $f$ since this is the only matrix whose values I can change, unlike $A$ which has constant values.
I suppose this problem will involve linear programming or something of that sort. Thank you in advance!
